# Android layouts and fragments in Oculus (Gear VR)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, oculus, gear-vr

I am very new to Oculus and Unity. I have an Android app and I want to port it to Gear VR. But I would like to reuse the most of the components: layouts and the networking communication layer which is exposed to the separate module.

Is it possible to place fragments on the 3d panes created it Unity?
Is it possible to use Android module or lib in Unity project for Oculus?

Or if I want to create a VR version of my app I need to develop in from scratch?

Comment: Is your current app built in Java? Are you using any middleware, or just making direct OpenGL calls?

Comment: I have an Android project (java) which has all the standard Android components - Activities, Fragments and xml layouts. And I want to port it on Oculus.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the Oculus Mobile SDK? (linked below). It sees likely that you will have to rewrite a great deal of your application if you are using high level Android UI features, since Gear operates at a much lower level.
https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/mobile/0.6.2.0/Oculus_Mobile_SDK/